# Can you send picture message using a Windows Live Messenger API/SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-live-messenger

Is there a way to send a picture message via a Windows Live SDK/API of some sort, to one of your messenger contacts?

I've been searching for about an hour, and seen mentions of some REST web services, and oAuth being the way to do it.

Could anybody point me in the right direction, or give a quick code example, as I have been searching for a while and coming up with nothing.

Closest I found was a Windows Live SDK v4.1 that contains a single DLL

```
Microsoft.Live.AuthHandler.dll
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, I do not want to just start a file transfer. I want to embed the picture into a message if that makes sense